# Subquery - execution sequence

Tags: sql

I have this query but I'm not understanding properly how it works.

In subqueries, the inner query is executed first and then the outer query is executed right? So in this case this inner query

```
select salary 
from hr.employees emp 
where salary > 1000 
  and emp.department_id = dep.department_id
```

will be executed first but this query needs the `dep.department_id`, so this inner query depends on the outer query right? So in this case the inner query is also executed first? Can you explain how the sequence of the query is or how it works in practice? Thanks!

```
select 
    department_name
from 
    hr.departments dep 
where 
    exists (select salary from hr.employees emp 
            where salary > 1000 and emp.department_id = dep.department_id);
```

Comment: I'd say, logically, the subquery is executed once for each row coming from FROM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "this query gets executed first and that query last". The inner query acts as a predicate for rows from outer query.

From logic point of view, the `from` clause of outer query is executed first and for each relation (i.e. department in your case) the inner query is executed. Each row in outer query substitutes fixed values into inner query where alias `dep` is used.

For example for some row of outer query the inner query behaves like `select salary from hr.employees emp where salary > 1000 and emp.department_id = 1`, for some other row like `select salary from hr.employees emp where salary > 1000 and emp.department_id = 2` etc. (Note the actual columns in `select` clause are not important here, select 1 would do the same.)

From implementation point of view there can be some optimizations but I currently assume this is not what you want for understanding the sense of the query.

Comment: Thanks, canyou explain why the column name 'salary' is not important and can be '1'? Also so the inner query acts as a predicate for rows from outer query.only in this example of the question or subqueries work like that? So For example in the query in question, the outer query is executed first and for each row of the departments table the where clause with the subquery is executed to check if the row stays or is discarded of the result set?

Comment: But for example in this query "SELECT employee_id, first_name, last_name FROM employees WHERE department_id IN (SELECT department_id FROM departments WHERE location_id = 1700)" works the same way? Or first the inner query is executed to get the department_id where location_id = 1700 and then the result of the inner query is passed to the outer query? Thanks!

Comment: ad 1st question: to first part: because `exists` clause tests if inner query has some rows, no matter what content is in them. (Even `select null` would work, row with null value in column is still a row and exists evaluates to true, although many SQL developers including me don't like it for not being instructive.) To second part: leave the mindset "query is executed first". Query execution means compiling source to plan and evaluating such plan in something like plain loops over btrees and hashtables. In some point of evalution, current loop variables are fixated and used in inner query.

Comment: ad 2nd question: you can type practically any query as inner query but in most cases it has real sense if the query somehow relates to outer query. Your example is possible, the inner query evaluates independently on particular row in outer query, so it is conceptually equivalent to enumeration of values, say, `... in (17000,17001,17002,17003)`. I didn't try and may be wrong but I guess it actually executes with same plan as join - `select e.* from employees e join departments d using (department_id) where d.location_id = 1700`.

Comment: Thanks, but so in this query "SELECT employee_id, first_name, last_name FROM employees WHERE department_id IN (SELECT department_id FROM departments WHERE location_id = 1700)" the sql compiler will read each row from employees and for each row will do another select for the WHERE condition?

Comment: For example if are returned 5 rows from the employees table in the outer query, the inner query is executed 5 times? Or the inner query is executed, gets all department ids and then are only executed two queries, the inner query at first to get the department ids and then the outter query using the result of the outer query?

Comment: First, compiler does not read table rows, that's the work of execution engine. Second, your counting queries does not make sense, you should still have in mind the syntactic appearance of query does not have to correlate with execution plan and primarily, *you don't need to know it*.

Answer (score 2):

> In subqueries, the inner query is executed first and then the outer query is executed right?

No.  You are missing a fundamental points about SQL.  It is a descriptive language not a procedural language.

A SQL query describes the result set that is produced.  It does not specify the exact processing.  In fact, what gets processed generally looks nothing like a query.  It is a directed acyclic graph (DAG) of various dataflow operations.

The SQL compiler/optimizer generates the DAG.

Comment: Can you explain better using for example the query of the question? Because it can be a descriptive language but the query must have some sequence to be executed right? Thanks!

Comment: @Oscar . . . The sequence is determined by the *optimizer*.    Period.  Only think about the operations you want for the result set . . . Of course, different databases work differently, but you have only tagged SQL generically.

Comment: Thanks again. But to write a sql query is necessary to know which is the sequence no? For example in case of subqueries as I ask in the question but also in other cases for example in queries when to use group by or where we need to know the sequence to write the query no? (Im a beginner)

Comment: @Oscar . . . No.  You need to know what the syntax does but not specifically how a given database turns it into executable code.